# Layering not working as expected

Tags: css

So I am trying to have two divs that are side by side, however, they always seem to overlap see...
[JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkbAr/4)

I tried messing with the z index but that didn't seem to help.

This should be easy anyone able to help me?

Comment: hm... but which ones should be side-by-side and on what edge?

Answer (score 1):

Try `float:left` on both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Add `float:left;` to `#content #item2`. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkbAr/5/).